# Invalid Host on Flutter dio GET Request

Tags: flutter, dio

I was fetching data from a database and presenting it in a table using Django. Even though the host/URL is correct, when using a GET request in Flutter using [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio), it still showed an error saying "invalid host." However, the data fetched using the GET request is visible in the browser. On the other hand, the POST request runs without any issues.

Comment: To help you with this issue we need to have more information. This host that you are trying to reach is running locally on the same machine that you are trying to run your Flutter app or is it in somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> //add this line
<application ...
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a issue where data from Django rest framework was not showing in Flutter through Dio. But in Postman everything was alright.

I thought problem was in Flutter. Then I found out I didn't allowed host in Django settings.py file. I added this

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
'10.0.2.2',
'127.0.0.1',
]
```

and at the end of the file added this
`CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True`

It solved my problem.